# Formatting date with ember js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I read about registering my own handlebars helper to display the date format I want. I read too that I could use a new transform type to use on my model. However, the examples in the docs are so simple that it doesn't help me.

When I call my model's property in my handlebars (for examples {{message.created_at}} where created_at is the above date)

2015-02-12T19:00:00.000-05:00 (february 12th for information)

How can I display this date with a time ago stamp? For example, if I sent the message at 9:00 am and it is 9:05, I want to display 5 minutes ago.

Comment: you could use `moment.js` library

Answer (score 2):

Write a computed property on `created_at` and use it in your template.

Answer (score 1):

As @Artych suggested, you could use moment.js in combination with a transform if you know you want to transform ALL dates

```
`import DS from 'ember-data'`

DateTransform = DS.Transform.extend
  deserialize: (serialized) ->
    #transform date here

  serialize: (deserialized) ->
    deserialized

`export default DateTransform`
```

Alternatively, if you want to have more control over where in your app this happens, a computed property is probably your best bet:

```
humanizedDate: (->
  moment(@get('model.created_at')).duration().humanize()
).property('model.created_at')
```